# Using loops in Postman Flows

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I have this simple use case: I would like to send an request with Postman Flows, with variables when both variables can have 2 values (foo is foo1 or foo2, bar is bar1 or bar2). And I'd like this request to be sent 4 times, with the values foo1-bar1, foo1-bar2 foo2-bar1 and foo2-bar2.

To my surprise, this simple workflow shows me that the request is issued 2 times with the values "foo1-bar1" and "foo2-bar2"...

[image]

for the sake of the demo, I use here a template, but it is exactly the same with a request...

Thank you